# Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm

Tags: oracle, perl, installation, perl-module, dbd

```
[Sun Feb 07 14:21:13.653134 2016]
[cgi:error] [pid 5059] [client 192.168.2.1:58208]
AH01215: Can't locate DBD/Oracle.pm in @INC (@INC contains:   
   /home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/
   /home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto
   lib /wm/libs
       /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5  
       /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
       /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
.) at /kk/kk/kk/DB.pm line 27.
```

I have install DBD::Oracle below is the directory structure

```
[x@ip-192-168-1-2 DBD-Oracle-1.74]$ tree /home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/auto
├── auto
│   ├── DBD
│   │   ├── Oracle
│   │   │   ├── dbdimp.h
│   │   │   ├── mk.pm
│   │   │   ├── ocitrace.h
│   │   │   ├── Oracle.h
│   │   │   └── Oracle.so
│   │   └── Oracle.pm
```

Also i have a sample script to test whether its actually works, and guess what this script works fine

```
[x@ip-192-168-1-2 Util]$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBD::Oracle;
use DBD::Oracle qw(ORA_RSET);
```

But when try running DBD::Oracle module from one of the .pm through cgi on apache its gives top error.Unable to figure out exact error .

Alos Oracle client is installed ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set.

Comment: How did you install?

Comment: installed oracle client, DBI then set paths and then DBD::Oracle ......did i missed something ......do u have specific guidelines

Comment: I just thought that you created the DBD::Oracle and copied it to this machine. Can you check if this works by addind `use lib '/home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/auto'` to the top of your script?

Comment: already that in PATH but no luck

Comment: `/home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto` and `/home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/auto` are different.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: `/home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/DBD/auto`, compared to this: `/home/x/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto`. Looks like you added an extra `DBD` in the directory when you installed the module.

Comment: ???? Its installed on its own .....i didn't added....well what could be right fix ?